# Como fazer efeito de sublinhado controlando o tamanho do sublinhado

Tags: css, css3

Como fazer um titulo ter um sublinhado, mas conseguir controlar o tamanho desse sublinhado.

Segue um exemplo do pretendido:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Cara editei minha resposta e inclui outro exemplo, acho que pode te interessar tb

Comment: Sim eu vi, impecável, ajudou bastante

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Opção 1**

Aqui tem um exemplo usar um `pseudo-elemento` ele é baseado em medidas em `EM` e `%`, assim quando vc mudar o tamanho da font `REM` o elemento muda proporcionalmente.

Vc tb pode mudar esse valor manualmente caso queira. *Deixei comentado no código*

```css
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
h1::after, h2::after, h3::after, h4::after, h5::after, h6::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 110%; /* posição da linha abaixo do texto relativa a altura do pai */
  left: 0;
  width: 40%; /* comprimento da linha relativa ao tamanho do texto */
  height: 0.2em; /* altura da linha relativa ao valor da font do pai */
  background-color: black;
}
h2::after {
    height: 1px; /* altura fixa customizado */
}
h4::after {
    width: 100px; /* comprimento fixo customizado */
}
h6::after {
    background-color: red; /* cor customizada */
}
```

```html
<h1>Meu H1</h1><br>
<h2>Meu H2</h2><br> <!-- exemplo com largura da linha fixa -->
<h3>Meu H3</h3><br>
<h4>Meu H4</h4><br> <!-- exemplo comprimento da linha fixo -->
<h5>Meu H5</h5><br>
<h6>Meu H6</h6><br> <!-- exemplo com cor diferente -->
```

**Opção 2**

Como é um `pseudo-elemento` e ele aceita a propriedade `content:""`, vc pode inclusive colocar uma imagem ali, ou então um caractere *Unicode* como nesse exemplo

```css
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
h1::after, h2::after, h3::after, h4::after, h5::after, h6::after {
  content: "\279E"; /* caractere unicode */
  position: absolute;
  top: 110%; 
  left: 0;
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 0; /* valores de font */
  font-size: 1.25em; /* valores de font */
  color: green; /* valores de font */
}

h2::after{
  content: url(http://www.placecage.com/16/16); /* img no content com url() */
  position: absolute;
  top: 110%; 
  left: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 16px; /* altura da imagem */
  width: 16px; /* largura da imagem */
}
h6::after{
  color: red; /* cor da fonte "seta", essa valor normalmente é herdado do pai, mas vc pode sobrescreve-lo aqui */
}
```

```html
<h1>Meu H1</h1><br>
<h2>Meu H2</h2><br> <!-- exemplo com imagem -->
<h3>Meu H3</h3><br>
<h4>Meu H4</h4><br>
<h5>Meu H5</h5><br>
<h6>Meu H6</h6><br> <!-- exemplo com color diferente -->
```

Comment: Perfeito ajudou bastante :D